# "Говорить через губу" - грамотно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Грамотно ли употреблять выражение "Говорить через губу"?

Answer (score 4):

Вполне, если это не официальный документ. Это разговорный фразеологизм. Говорить через губу — говорить нехотя, с презрением.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё есть выражение "Через губу не плюнет" (о человеке надменном, ставящем себя выше других)